# Django ManyToMany Inlines Ordering in 1.2.x

Tags: python, django, inlines, modeladmin

I'm using Django 1.2's new ManyToMany admin.TabularInline to display related objects in the admin app, and it works great except I can't figure out what to set the "ordering" property to so it can sort by one of the cross-referenced field names.

For instance:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Bar(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    foos = models.ManyToManyField(Foo)

class FooBarInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Bar.foos.through
    ordering = ('name', )  # DOES NOT WORK
    raw_id_fields = ('name', )  # THROWS EXCEPTION

class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (FooBarInline, )

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
```

How can I get to the Foo.name field to order by it in the inline?

Comment: Have you tried `'foo__name'`?

Comment: 'FooBarInline.raw_id_fields' refers to field 'foo__name' that is missing from model 'Bar_foos'.

Answer (score 3):

The model [ordering meta option](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/options/#ordering) designates the order of the inline elements.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
```

If you needed to have the ordering of the admin model different from your primary ordering, you could do something like this:

```
class Foo_Extended(Foo):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
```

And use Foo_Extended for your AdminInline model.

I'm assuming you know this, but Django 1.3 adds and ordering option to the InlineAdmin model but I know you said Django 1.2

Answer (score 0):

I think you may override

```
ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

You can find details in the docs for [ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey).